# Best way to convert for-loops into an FPGA

Tags: signal-processing, verilog, fpga

I am having trouble wrapping my head how to best replicate some C code in an FPGA using a for-loop (not my first time being stuck on this).

The snippet of C code look like this:

```
dot_product(&corr_sum, &sample_data_buffer[sample_index+d_circ_buf_size-sync_pattern_size], &sync_pattern[0], sync_pattern_size);
abs_corr_sum += abs(corr_sum);
```

Pretty straightforward, it is taking the dot product of two complex vectors and doing a cumulative sum of it.

And he was my attempt to replicate it:

```
always @(sample_index)
begin
    // for each incoming sample
    abs_corr_sum = 64'd0;
    corr_sum = 64'd0;
    for (index2 = 0; index2 < sync_pattern_size; index2 = index2 + 1'b1)
    begin
        corr_sum = sample_data_buffer_I[index2+sample_index+circ_buf_size-sync_pattern_size] * sync_pattern_I[index2]
                   + sample_data_buffer_Q[index2+sample_index+circ_buf_size-sync_pattern_size] * sync_pattern_Q[index2];

        //this is my quick and dirty abs(corr_sum) summer
        abs_corr_sum = (corr_sum < 0) ? abs_corr_sum + ~$signed(corr_sum)+1 : abs_corr_sum + corr_sum;
    end // for (index2 = 0; index2 < sync_pattern_size; index2 = index2 + 1'b1)
end //always @(sample_index)
```

Does this seem right?  I am not getting the results I am expecting; and though the issue could be elsewhere, I think that this section is the most likely culprit.

Comment: It very much depends; are you looking to do this calculation all in a single clock step, or in multiple clocks (assuming this design has a clock)? At very least, you should change `always @(sample_index)` to `always @(*)` or `always_comb` if your synthesis tool supports SystemVerilog (note that Vivado and QuartusII both do!)

Comment: @Unn, it is a clocked design and I am hoping to have the cumulative sum created on each clock, I just thought that to do the cumulative sum, it couldn't be in a clocked loop, so I went with the always@.  I'll try changing to the @(*), but for the other option, I'll have to research what always_comb is, that is new to me.  I am using Vivado for this.

Comment: Verilog (IEEE-1364) has been replaced by the superset SystemVerilog (IEEE-1800). SystemVerilog became a standard in 2005, so most modern tools support at least most of its core features (though alot of the fancier stuff isnt implemented yet). As `always @(*)` and `always @(posedge)` can easily result in bad code, SystemVerilog introduces `always_comb` and `always_ff` which provide nice ways of doing the same things `always @(*)` and `always @(posedge)` did, but they better simulate hardware and include a number of checks to confirm the design translates to hardware nicely.

Comment: As for your code, if you want to calculate an entire dot product in a single step, realize this means a separate combinational multiplier for each element pair (ie, n-1 mults for n sized vector). This can result in alot of area, which might not fit on your FPGA depending on which you are using. Also, side note, the line assigning `abs_corr_sum` should go more like so: `abs_corr_sum += (corr_sum[63]) ? -corr_sum : corr_sum;` Or you can leave the `corr_sum < 0` so long as `corr_sum` is declared `signed`

Answer (score 2):

To convert a piece of code coming from an algorithm with loops, conditionals, et al, into a synthesizable form of Verilog, you need to translate it in to a FSM.

For example, a for loop to do something similar you are asking for would be:

```
int sample_I[N], sync_I[N]; // assume 32-bit ints, 2-complement numbers.
int sample_Q[N], sync_Q[N];
int i, corsum, abscorsum = 0;

for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  corsum = sample_I[i] * sync_I[i] + sample_Q[i] * sync_Q[i];
  abscorsum += abs(corsum);
}
```

First, group sentences into time slots, so you can see which actions can be done in the same clock cycle (same state), and assign a state to each slot:

---

1)

```
i = 0
abscorsum = 0
goto 2)
```

---

2)

```
if i!=N    
  corsum = sample_I[i] * sync_I[i]
  goto 3)
else
  goto 5)
```

---

3)

```
corsum = corsum + sample_Q[i] * sync_Q[i]
i = i + 1
goto 4)
```

---

4)

```
if (corsum >= 0)
  abscorsum = abscorsum + corsum
else
  abscorsum = abscorsum + (-corsum)
goto 2)
```

---

5)

```
STOP
```

---

States 2 and 3 may be merged into a single state, but that would force the synthesizer to infer two multipliers, and besides, the propagation delay of the resulting combinatorial path could be very high, limiting the clock frequency allowable for this design. So, I have split the dot product calculation into two parts, each one them using a single multiplication operation. The synthesizer, if instructed so, can use one multiplier and share it for the two operations, as both happen in different clock cycles.

which translates to this module:
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/MEG

Signal `rst` is used to signal the module to start operation. `finish` is raised by the module to signal end of operation and validness of output (`abscorrsum`)

`sample_I`, `sync_i`, `sample_Q` and `sync_Q` are modeled using memory blocks, with `i` being the address of the element to read. Most synthesizers will infer block RAMs for these vectors, as each of them is read only in one state, and always with the same address signal.

```
module corrdotprod #(N=4) (
  input wire clk,
  input wire rst,
  output reg [31:0] i,
  input wire [31:0] sample_i,
  input wire [31:0] sync_i,
  input wire [31:0] sample_q,
  input wire [31:0] sync_q,
  output reg [31:0] abscorrsum,
  output reg finish
);

  parameter
    STATE1 = 3'd1,
    STATE2 = 3'd2,
    STATE3 = 3'd3,
    STATE4 = 3'd4,
    STATE5 = 3'd5;

  reg [31:0] corrsum;
  reg [2:0] state;

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst == 1'b1) begin
      state <= STATE1;
    end
    else begin
      case (state)
        STATE1:
          begin
            i <= 0;
            abscorrsum <= 0;
            finish <= 1'b0;
            state <= STATE2;
          end
        STATE2:
          begin
            if (i!=N) begin
              corrsum <= sample_i * sync_i; // synthesizer deals with multiplication
              state <= STATE3;
            end
            else begin
              state <= STATE5;
            end
          end
        STATE3:
          begin
            corrsum <= corrsum + sample_q * sync_q; // this product can share the multiplier as above
            i <= i + 1;
            state <= STATE4;
          end
        STATE4:
          begin
            if (corrsum[31] == 1'b0) // remember: 2-complement
              abscorrsum <= abscorrsum + corrsum;
            else
              abscorrsum <= abscorrsum + (~corrsum+1);
            state <= STATE2;
          end
        STATE5:
          finish <= 1'b1;
      endcase      
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Which can be tested with this simple test bench:

```
module tb;
  reg clk;
  reg rst;
  reg [31:0] sample_i[0:3];
  reg [31:0] sync_i[0:3];
  reg [31:0] sample_q[0:3];
  reg [31:0] sync_q[0:3];
  wire [31:0] i;
  wire [31:0] abscorrsum;

  corrdotprod #(.N(4)) uut  (clk, rst, i, sample_i[i], sync_i[i], sample_q[i], sync_q[i], abscorrsum, finish);

  integer tb_i, tb_corrsum, tb_abscorrsum;
  initial begin
    $dumpfile ("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars (0, tb.uut);    

    sample_i[0] = 1;
    sample_i[1] = 2;
    sample_i[2] = 3;
    sample_i[3] = 4;

    sync_i[0] = 2;
    sync_i[1] = -2;
    sync_i[2] = 2;
    sync_i[3] = -2;

    sample_q[0] = -1;
    sample_q[1] = -2;
    sample_q[2] = -3;
    sample_q[3] = -4;

    sync_q[0] = 3;
    sync_q[1] = -3;
    sync_q[2] = 3;
    sync_q[3] = -3;

    clk = 0;

    rst = 1;
    #30;
    rst = 0;
    wait (finish == 1);
    $display ("ABSCORRSUM    = %d\n", abscorrsum);

    // Testing result from module
    tb_abscorrsum = 0;
    for (tb_i = 0; tb_i < 4; tb_i = tb_i + 1) begin
      tb_corrsum = sample_i[tb_i] * sync_i[tb_i] + sample_q[tb_i] * sync_q[tb_i];
      if (tb_corrsum<0)
        tb_corrsum = -tb_corrsum;
      tb_abscorrsum = tb_abscorrsum + tb_corrsum;
    end
    $display ("TB_ABSCORRSUM = %d\n", tb_abscorrsum);

    $finish;
  end

  always begin
    clk = #5 !clk;
  end
endmodule
```